# R Comparison of integers seems to neglect number of digits

Tags: r, integer, comparison, truncation

I have coordinates in one dimension, which describe the beginning and end of a segment. I am trying to write a function, which tells me is one segment is within another. This is what I have, in this case to see if b is inside a:

```
isin <- function(a, b){

if (a[beginning] <= b[beginning] && a[end] >= b[end]){
  return TRUE
}
```

The problem is, that it does not seem to respect different lengths of the numbers, for example:

```
a <- c(2345, 2380)
b <- c(234600, 237900)
isin(a, b)
TRUE
```

Its as if the two numbers are put side by side starting from the first, and anything non overlapping is truncated. I am pretty new to this stuff, so excuse me if I am missing some basic property of integers.

Comment: That has no chance of working: 1. where are `beginning` and `end` defined, 2. `return` is a function and requires its argument to be given in parentheses, etc. Try `isin <- function(a, b) a[1] <= b[1] && a[length(a)] >= b[length(b)]`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that by beginning and end you mean the last first and last element of a vector, this should work:

```
isin <- function(a, b){

  if (a[1] <= b[1] & a[length(a)] >= b[length(b)]){
  # using length() to get the last element of vector
    return(TRUE)
  } else {return(FALSE)}

}
```

Using your example:

```
> a <- c(2345, 2380)
> b <- c(234600, 237900)
> isin(a, b)
[1] FALSE
```

An example where it returns TRUE:

```
> a <- c(1, 9)
> b <- c(9, 1)
> isin(a, b)
[1] TRUE
```